# Connecting Rest API to Google Charts

Tags: javascript, html, css, mysql, node.js

I created an API to pull data from MySQL. What I’m trying to do is connect the output from my API to Google Charts (specifically a column chart). 
Any idea of how I would go about this? The APIs output is JSON data.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily connect your API data to the Google map easily from this sample.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'bar']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTrendlines);

function drawTrendlines() {
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('timeofday', 'Time of Day');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Motivation Level');
      data.addColumn('number', 'Energy Level');

      data.addRows([
        [{v: [8, 0, 0], f: '8 am'}, 1, .25],
        [{v: [9, 0, 0], f: '9 am'}, 2, .5],
        [{v: [10, 0, 0], f:'10 am'}, 3, 1],
        [{v: [11, 0, 0], f: '11 am'}, 4, 2.25],
        [{v: [12, 0, 0], f: '12 pm'}, 5, 2.25],
        [{v: [13, 0, 0], f: '1 pm'}, 6, 3],
        [{v: [14, 0, 0], f: '2 pm'}, 7, 4],
        [{v: [15, 0, 0], f: '3 pm'}, 8, 5.25],
        [{v: [16, 0, 0], f: '4 pm'}, 9, 7.5],
        [{v: [17, 0, 0], f: '5 pm'}, 10, 10],
      ]);

      var options = {
        title: 'Motivation and Energy Level Throughout the Day',
        trendlines: {
          0: {type: 'linear', lineWidth: 5, opacity: .3},
          1: {type: 'exponential', lineWidth: 10, opacity: .3}
        },
        hAxis: {
          title: 'Time of Day',
          format: 'h:mm a',
          viewWindow: {
            min: [7, 30, 0],
            max: [17, 30, 0]
          }
        },
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)'
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

```html
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```